# Excel - String in a single Row to Characters in Multiple Column

Tags: string, excel, vba, character, row

I'm new to Excel VB. Currently , I want to do following -

Read from a Cell. Something like this "010111" (in Binary). Lets say its in sheet 1, Cell A10.
Write into multiple cells the same information like this. Lets say in sheet 2. Cell B1 to B6. like , Sheet 2 - B1 -0
Sheet 2 - B2 -1
Sheet 2 - B3 -0
Sheet 2 - B4 -1
Sheet 2 - B5 -1
Sheet 2 - B6 -1
Also, I want to make it generic, I mean I wanted to have a for loop or something like which can do this for dynamic cells. i.e, from sheet 1 - A(i) to sheet 2 - B(j) to B(j+n).

Please help me out? Is this possible to read individual character from the string. I assume that we can take the binary as string & read each character & can then put them one by one into column rows making it dynamic for any row/column.

Thank you,
Prateek

Comment: could you please provide a code you've tried so far? together with a screenshot of your data sample, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately , I cannot post images at the moment.

Comment: then the coud you've so far pls

Comment: @psychicebola I found an answer to myself. Please check the answer posted by me.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, simpler to understand for myself. Anyways thanks for all your suggestion. I couldn't post the reply as was busy developing the tool. Here's small piece of code for you guys.

```
'Our first Job is to define the range.
```

'Here I'm selecting D10 to K10. You can check same while debugging the number of 'rows & column.

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = Range("D10", "K10")

'Define the counter variables

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For Each cel In rng

```
If Len(cel) > 0 Then

    For i = 1 To Len(cel)
```

'Extract a single character from the string Cel

'MID( Input_string, Start_position, Number_of_characters )

```
        char = Mid(cel.Value, i, 1)
```

'Decide what you want to do with the values

```
        If char = 0 Then
```

'Select the sheet & cell location where you want to Print

```
          Sheet4.Cells(9 + j, 1).Value =  char + " Hey Prateek,Its a Zero"

        ElseIf char = 1 Then
```

'Select the sheet & cell location where you want to Print

```
            char = 180

            Sheet4.Cells(9 + j, 1).Value =  char + " Hey Prateek, Its a One"

        End If
```

'Perform this If you want to write this at another location as well

```
        'oFile.WriteLine Sheet4.Cells(9 + j, 1).Value
```

'Loop the characters & then Increment the Rows in your destination

```
       j = j + 1
```

'Loop for the next cell

```
    Next i

End If
```

Next cel

[image: The values in the image are just for representation, Run the code to see actual answer]

You can also read same at

[From Cell to multiple cells in Column](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/876163-cell-multiple-cells-column.html)
Regards ,
Patrick Dew

Have a Nice time with your Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough sketch of how you could do this:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer, targetCol As Integer, targetRow As Integer
Dim char As String
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

targetCol = 2 ' Set the target column to col. "B"
targetRow = 1 ' Set the target Row, starts at row 1 (B1)

lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'assuming your data in column A is a bunch of strings you want to break out, without
    ' any gaps, this will find the last row

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))

For Each cel In rng
    If Len(cel) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(cel)
            Cells(targetRow + i - 1, targetCol).Value = Mid(cel.Value, i, 1)
        Next i
        targetRow = targetRow + Len(cel)

    End If
Next cel


End Sub
```

It takes my A1:A4 range, and pastes into Col. B, starting at row 1:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I would definitely try this out & put the details if I could exactly do what I wanted.